# What is '$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)' doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the following doing, and why is it at the top of the page?

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll.rb

Comment: +1 in sympathy for encountering one of the ugliest bits of Ruby. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395688/unshift-file-join-in-ruby

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's adding the current file's directory to the load path. `$:` represents the load path (which is an array) and `unshift` prepends to the beginning of the array.

The reason it's there (and at the top) is so that all those requires needn't worry about the path.

Comment: thanks for your answer. what is the benefit/significance of adding something in the load path? One could just use `require` to access a ruby file, right?

Answer (score 10):

Technically it is adding the path of the file as the first entry of the load path that ruby uses to look for files.  $: is a magic variable and more clearly referenced by $LOAD_PATH.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 > $LOAD_PATH
 => ["/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 > $:
 => ["/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 > $:.unshift '.'
 => [".", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/Users/wesbailey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0"]
```

Comment: I know this was a very old question, but is there a reason for adding it to the head rather than the tail (with push, say) ? Is this so that it takes precedence in a Union like manner over files with the same name ? (A hotfix folder).

Comment: @mckenzm Yes.  You add it to the head because you want the file in the current directory to be discovered first in the load path.  The load path is traversed in order from first to last when looking for files.

Comment: That's what I was driving at, so for development, Unit Testing directories take precedence over Integration Testing directories etc.

Answer (score 3):

It add the current working directory path to all the require used in the project, After adding this on the top we don't need to bother about the file path we are requiring, but all the file we are requiring must be in the same directory where our main program requiring other files.

$: is reserved key word to load the path.