# ruby $:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)

Tags: ruby

I see this a lot in many ruby scripts but not sure what it means:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is '$:.unshift File.dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)' doing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155995/what-is-unshift-file-dirname-file-doing)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`$:` is just a shortcut for `$LOAD_PATH`. `__FILE__` is the relative path to the script. This adds the current script directory to the load path.

Comment: And add this directory first, so it has priority over the rest. Right?

Answer (score 12):

ruby comes with a set of predefined variables:

$:
The array contains the list of places to look for Ruby scripts and binary modules by load or require. It initially consists of the arguments to any -I command line switches, followed by the default Ruby library, probabl "/usr/local/lib/ruby", followed by ".", to represent the current directory. (Mnemonic: colon is the separators for PATH environment variable.)

See here for more:
http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/variable.html#colon

another link:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142378#631564

Answer (score 1):

Another example is:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__))
require "aws-inventory"
require "aws_inventory/cli"

AwsInventory::CLI.start(ARGV)
```

Which makes sure the current dir is included in the $LOAD_PATH and class AwsInventory::CLI.start(ARGV) is called