# require cannot load such file while writing a sample code

Tags: ruby, rubygems

require cannot load file

**the following is code**

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname('./test/ss.rb')
require "test/version"
require "test/ss"
```

**output:**

```
ruby test_require.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- ss (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from test_require.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

how to make require 'ss' work

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: cannot call ss.rb with require 'ss'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa OP though,he added the directory to the `$LOAD_PATH`, but then why *load error* is coming.. But OP's approach is incorrect.

Comment: require_relative 'ss' will work. But not the right way.

Comment: dont understand why require 'test/version' is passed. Both ss.rb and version.rb are in test folder

Answer (score 0):

It is good to use [`#unshift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-unshift) method not, [`#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C), [The reason it's there (and at the top) is so that all those requires needn't worry about the path.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5156130/2767755) :

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname('./test_require/ss.rb')
```

Comment: @aashish what is the actual path of `/test/ss.rb`

Comment: as it is have a file test_require.rb where i am calling require 'ss'

Comment: You are not correct directory in the *load path*. Thus the error. Check it carefully..once added only `require filename` is enough, if the directory of the file you added to the *load path*.